# Graphics Card 250mhz is this normal?

Tags: windows, graphics-card

My graphics card is running slower than I think it should be.

My specs are:

- Core i5 2500k
- Asus p8Z68-v PRO
- ASUS Radeon 6950 DirectCuII 2GB
- Antec Twelve Hundred
- Seagate 1TB 7200rpm 32MB cache HDD
- 850W Seasonic M12D
- 8GB Muskin Blackline RAM

On idle my CPU sits at around 30%. My GPU clock spikes between 250MHz and 810MHz and my Memory clock spikes between 150mhz and 1250MHz.

Even when running Furmark is still spikes up and down.

Furmark Averages 35fps at 1920x1080 no AA.

It is a fresh Windows installation, new components and all drivers have been updated. Is this all normal?

Comment: It's not too abnormal for your GPU to downclock. However, 250MHz does seem slow. What does Catalyst say? Are you doing any overclocking on the GPU? What is causing your CPU to sit at 30%? that's excessive for idle.

Comment: Also, memory downclocking to that low is also abnormal.

Comment: Hi, I have done no OCing at all, ever. This is all stock. Catalyst shows the spikes between 250 and 810. I haven't really got anything running that should cause the CPU to sit so high, but its sitting at 8% right now.

Answer (score 1):

This is all normal. The components reduce their clocks when they're not under load to conserve power and reduce heat. When you see the CPU, for example, at 30% load, that's 30% of what it's capable of at the very low clocking speed. It's not 30% of its actual potential.